# REST API naming best practices

Tags: node.js, api, rest, backend

I have two collections: **Transactions** and **Wallets**. Each `Transaction` has a WalletId reference to `Wallet`.

I'm trying to create an API that fetches the list of Transactions belonging to a Wallet. I'm thinking about making it this way.

```
GET /transactions/wallets/:id
```

Since the user is trying to fetch **transactions**, I thought `/transactions` should come first.

On the other hand, my manager wants it to be like this:

```
GET /wallets/:id/transactions
```

Which one is better? Which one follows the best practices?

How can I defend my perspective?

Answer (score 0):

As I was looking around, I found this [example by `Github API`](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#list-repositories-for-a-user) that returns the repositories of a specific user.

Turns out they are using the same Design my manager was asking for:

```
/users/{user}/repos
```

In conclusion, we'll go for the second option:

```
/wallets/{wallet}/transactions
```

Yet, it is worth noticing that this API endpoint should be kept under `transactions` in the API Documentation as Github people kept their endpoint documentation under `repos`.

Answer (score -1):

> REST API naming best practices

REST does not care what spelling conventions you use for your resource identifiers.

```
/transactions/wallets/:id
/wallets/:id/transactions
/:id/nonsequiturs
/cf7eb28c-3d78-47a7-b1b0-a7057895485f
```

All of these are *fine*, as far as REST is concerned.  The identifier is just an identifier.  Think of it like a key that is used to access a document in a hash/map/dictionary.

> Which one is better?

The one that makes things easier for the human beings that you are going to prioritize.  The *machines* don't care, so you should try to make things better for (a) users who are looking at URI in their browser history or (b) technical writers who are trying to document the resources or (c) operators who are trying to troubleshoot a problem reading entries in the web access logs or ....

> Having meaningful routes is as important as having meaningful variable names

Yes, exactly.

And in exactly the same way that your compilers/interpreters don't care whether you use good variable naming conventions or bad ones, so too do REST components not care whether you use good identifier spelling conventions or bad ones.

REST doesn't care, and therefore you the designer have extra degrees of freedom that you can use to satisfy other needs.

Comment: This is like saying you can name your variable `a` instead of `wallets` and your function `func` instead of `getWalletByUserId`. Having meaningful routes is as important as having meaningful variable names. It enables front end developers to easily use and interact with your API, thus helping your API stay alive and be used by many people.